# Outlook deletes/forgets settings

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Since a few days I observe the following behavior of my Outlook 2010: It seems to forget settings, which I define. For instance, I observed that my reading pane is gone. I then change the setting, that reading pane shall be displayed on the right hand side. When I close Outlook and reopen it, the reading pane again is gone.

Another example: I hit `CTRL+ENTER` to send mails. When I do this now, Outlook tells me *"You have just hit CTRL+ENTER. Do you want to send the e-Mail and Outlook to remember this setting?"* Then I hit yes and tick the box, so Outlook should not ask again the next time. However, when I close and reopen Outlook it does ask again. Hence, it forgot the setting (similar to the placement of the reading pane).

Any idea on why that issue occurs?

Comment: Is this your personal computer, or a company-owned/provided one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open Outlook, do you see at the top: (Safe mode)?

If so, then your outlook was launched in safe mode. Windows released an update which causes this to happen.

Although the update was released december 8th and Microsoft already removed it, you might still somehow gotten this update.

Go to your `Control Panel`, `Programs and Features` and at the left, choose `Uninstall Windows Updates`.

Now from the list, search for the following update: KB3114409 and uninstall it. Directly after you uninstalled the update, restart outlook and notice the (safe mode) is gone and everything works as expected.

Comment: after I left my office yesterday, I shut down my computer. Now I rebooted it, and the issue is gone. Unfortunately I couldn't check if Outlook indeed was in (Safe Mode) yesterday, but I am pretty sure, that this (i.e. the bad update you mention) was the issue. Could it be, that Windows automatically got rid of this update, after shut down/rebooting the system?

Comment: Windows removing an update by itself? unlikely. Its possible, but given you're in an office, its likely you also have an IT department, right? It is possible to combat the issue by altering a registry setting, something that can be deployed through a policy update. I bet your IT department did that when they got more complaints.